# Is there a name for this measure?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

For any given set $X$, define a measure $u$ on $\wp(X)$ where for all $A \in\wp( X)$: $$u(A)=0\text{ if }A\text{ is countable, and }u(A)=\infty\text{ otherwise}$$